How to relocate Tile3DLayer in Deck.GL
When loading data with Tile3DLayer, I want to change the position of the entire data on the map. I have tried various methods, such as using modelMatrix, accessing each sub-tile and changing the modelMatrix, adding a transformMatrix field in the tileset.json definition, using coordinateSystem: COORDINATE_SYSTEM.LNGLAT_OFFSETS and set value to coordinateOrigin... However, the data position still does not have any change. Please help with a solution to move the entire 3D Tile to a new location. Thank you

What programming language are you writing the code in, in order to use the deck.gl framework? Please tag it, for a start. Then please read [ask] and how to create a [mre].

This happens when loading Tile3DLayer from google maps, so far the only thing I've found that works is loading Tile3DLayer not as an overlay on top, but as the base interleaved.
